# Select all instances of component in React.js

Tags: audio, reactjs

I have a page where I am creating eight audio players, all from the same React class.

I use an `onclick()` handler to start and stop the audio for each player.

My issue is, it's possible for the players to play at the same time.

I want to have the ability within my component click handler to select all other components of the same class and to stop them, maybe using an `.each()` method.

What is the `React` way to do this?

Comment: Its 'possible' but its not recommended. React components should only interact through props. Use a callback to a shared parent to then propogate the playing prop to all the players and control it from that shared parent

Comment: It depends how on the structure. You could use events or triggers, properties, `refs`..., https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most React like way to do this would be to contain all of your audio players in a parent component. If the states of two components effect one another, that state should be moved into the nearest common parent component.